# MySQL database error, Unknown column X in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, join

I need help for fixing database error. I am new to MySQL. I am getting an error like this:

> Database error: Invalid SQL: CREATE TABLE gl2preethyd1495077842 AS
>   SELECT chart_id, sum(a.amount) as dr, sum(a.amount) as cr FROM
>   acc_trans a join gl b left outer join ar c ON a.trans_id=c.id WHERE if
>   ( c.service_completion is null, ( a.transdate <='' and a.transdate >=
>   '' ), ( c.service_completion <='' and c.service_completion >= '' ) )
>   and a.trans_id=b.id GROUP BY chart_id ORDER BY chart_id
>       MySQL Error: 1054 (Unknown column 'c.service_completion' in 'where clause')

Session halted.

```
CODE:

$sql =  "CREATE TABLE $temp2 AS " ;

$sql.=  "SELECT chart_id, sum(a.amount)  as dr, sum(a.amount) as cr FROM acc_trans a join gl b left outer join ar c ON a.trans_id=c.id " ;

$sql .="WHERE if ( c.service_completion is null, ( a.transdate <='$TB_ToDate' and a.transdate >= '$TB_FromDate' ), ( c.service_completion <='$TB_ToDate' and c.service_completion >= '$TB_FromDate' ) ) and a.trans_id=b.id ";

if ($attrib1<>'')       $sql .= " and attrib1=$attrib1 " ;
if ($attrib2<>'')       $sql .= " and attrib2=$attrib2 " ;
if ($attrib3<>'')       $sql .= " and attrib3=$attrib3 " ;
$sql.=  "GROUP BY chart_id ORDER BY chart_id" ;
```

I am unable to find the problem in my code.

Comment: What is the `CREATE TABLE x AS SELECT`? I am not sure this is valid SQL in MySQL. It looks like you are trying to create a view. Are you sure you are using MySQL? The question was originally also tagged as SQL Server. Which are you using, what version, and what do you expect this code to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self explanatory:

> Error: 1054 (Unknown column 'c.service_completion' in 'where clause')

Check the following line:

```
$sql .="WHERE if ( c.service_completion is null, ( a.transdate <='$TB_ToDate' and a.transdate >= '$TB_FromDate' ), ( c.service_completion <='$TB_ToDate' and c.service_completion >= '$TB_FromDate' ) ) and a.trans_id=b.id ";
```

Here `c.service_completion` is a column which is not present in the `ar` table (as c is an alias for ar table).

Comment: Thanks..One more doubt:

Comment: And what is that ?

Comment: $sql =  "CREATE TABLE $temp2 AS " ;
$sql.=  "SELECT chart_id, sum(amount)  as dr, sum(amount) as cr FROM acc_trans a, gl b " ;
$sql.=  "WHERE a.transdate<='$report_date' and a.transdate>='2004-04-01' and a.trans_id=b.id " ;

Comment: showing this error on another page. can u please help me?Database error: Invalid SQL: CREATE TABLE gl2preethy.d1495079742 AS SELECT chart_id, sum(amount) as dr, sum(amount) as cr FROM acc_trans a, gl b WHERE a.transdate<='2017-04-20' and a.transdate>='2004-04-01' and a.trans_id=b.id GROUP BY chart_id ORDER BY chart_id
MySQL Error: 1049 (Unknown database 'gl2preethy')

Comment: There is no database with name `gl2preethy`. Please read  the error msg carefully

Comment: @MayankPandeyz: I've added a comment under the question, I wonder if the OP is trying to create a view. Is `CREATE TABLE x AS SELECT` accepted in MySQL? I've not seen that construction before.

Comment: Well, I think your answer was correct as well. We just need some clarifications from the OP.